# Let A be a non-zero vector in $R^n$ and let c be a fixed number. Show that the set of all elements X in $R^n$ such that $A*X \geq c$ is convex.

Tags: linear-algebra

I have this problem. I solved it, but I think there is a problem in my solution. Maybe I've misunderstood something. I'd be glad if someone told me whether there are any problems with my solution.
I also found a question about the same problem in another forum, where the solution is very different. This also makes me think that I am doing some errors.
Here is my solution.

Let $P = AX = a_1x_1 + a_2x_2 + ... a_ix_i \geq c$ where P is a point in X.
Let $Q = BX = b_1x_1 + b_2x_2 + ... b_ix_i \geq c$ where Q is a point in X and B is a non-zero vector in $R^n$.

Let $(1 - t)P + tQ$ be a line that connects P and Q where $0 \leq t \leq 1$.

As $P \geq c$ and $Q \geq c$, we find that
$(1 - t)P \geq (1 - t)c$ and $tQ \geq tc$. So $(1 - t)P + tQ \geq (1 - t)c + tc = c$

Now, explicating P and Q we get
$(1 - t)a_1x_1 + ... + (1 - t)a_ix_i + tb_1x_1 + ... + tb_ix_i \geq c$
$((1 - t)a_1 + tb_1)x_1 + ...+ ((1 - t)a_i + tb_i)x_i \geq c$

Let $c_i = (1 - t)a_i + tb_i$ and let $C$ be the vector $(c_1, c_2, ..., c_i)$.
Consequently $CX \geq c$.
Now if $t = 0$ then $C = A$ and if $t = 1$ then $C = B$.
So, $CX$ is between $P$ and $Q$ and $X$ is convex for $AX \geq c$.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You need $0\le t\le 1$ to conclude $(1-t)P\ge(1-t)c$ and $tQ\ge tc$.

Comment: Yes, I just edited the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote " where $P$ is a point in $X.$" This makes no sense, since $X$ is a vector and $P$ is a number.

Let $M:=\{ X \in \mathbb R^n:A*X \ge c\}$

Now let $X,Y \in M$ and $t \in [0,1].$ Then

$$A*(tX+(1-t)Y)=tA*X+(1-t)A*Y \ge tc+(1-t)c =c.$$

This shows that $tX+(1-t)Y \in M$. Hence $M$ is convex.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the solution! Besides that error, now I think it was useless to introduce the vector C.